# count member number in table not allowed to be more than one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This should be a relatively easy procedure to code but for some reason I am just not able to get it working.

**What Im trying to do**

Members enter a competition, you are only allowed to **enter once**. To stop members from entering more than once I use the following code

```
//Check If user allready entered comp
$sql="SELECT member_nr, count(member_nr) as entered FROM competition WHERE member_nr ='$memNr' and competition = '$comp'";
$result = mysql_query( $sql ) or trigger_error( mysql_error() . " in " . $sql );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $isEntered = $row['entered'];   
}//end while`

if($isEntered >1  ){
?>
    <h1>You have allready entered</h1>
<?
}//end check if entered allready
```

**My Problem**

Im getting the error Notice: U*ndefined offset: 1*

I cant for the live of me figure out why  am getting this, Im guessing my sql query is incorrect...any advice will be appreciated

Comment: 1 > 1 is evaluates to `false`. you might need to try `if($isEntered > 0){`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching one column and one field only, then why you use it in loop.

Simply use this instead,

```
$sql="SELECT member_nr, count(member_nr) as entered 
      FROM competition 
      WHERE member_nr ='$memNr' and competition = '$comp' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query( $sql ) or trigger_error( mysql_error() . " in " . $sql );

$isEntered = mysql_result($result,0);
if($isEntered > 1) echo "<h1>You have allready entered</h1>";
```

Other point is that, `mysql` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` is best.

Read : 
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thank you  sir, may I ask why you put a 0 (zero) in `mysql_result($result,0)`

Comment: Since you want to retrieve only one column and one row, `mysql_result($result,0);` where `0` is the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query is correct. However, you need to initialise the variable `$isEntered` to `0` somewhere at the beginning of your script, since it will be undefined in case the member id was not found at all in your table.

And ...

... you should no longer be using `mysql_..` functions. They are deprecated. Instead go for `mysqli_...` or `PDO`.